# probability of a quadratic function has real roots

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Let $A, B$ be independent random variables with uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.
>
> What is the probability that the quadratic equation $x^2 + 2A x + B = 0$ has real roots?

I obtained the answer $\frac{1}{3}$, is it correct?

Comment: You should include the steps you took to obtain the answer.

Comment: It boils down to computing $$\mathbb{P}[A^2\geq B]=\int_{0}^{1}\mathbb{P}[B\leq a^2]\,da = \int_{0}^{1}a^2\,da = \frac{1}{3}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct.

The probability of  $$ x^2 + 2A x + B = 0$$ having  real roots is the probability of $$ P(B\le A^2) $$

Which is  $$ \int _0 ^1 x^2 dx = 1/3 $$

Comment: Explicitly it is $P(A^2 \ge B)= \int _0 ^1 \int _0 ^{a^2} 1 db da = \frac{1}{3}  $, right?